# How to approximate the the 'owner' of lower level objects for a memory leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks

My heap histogram tells me I'm using lots of char arrays ([C), byte arrays ([B), hash nodes, and locks.

> What tool will tell me who 'owns' these character arrays, byte arrays, hash nodes and locks? I'm expecting that 'ownership' is very ambiguous so what are some methods and tools used to approximate it?

So far I've been following reverse pointers in visualvm starting from the char array, but this only gives me a qualitative feel for the problem. I want numbers.

One idea I had was to follow N (some constant) pointers backwards and group by the paths, summing over #instances and bytes. For example, if I were to jump two pointers backwards from the the character array, I might find the glutton leak:

```
MB        path
1000      char[] <- String <- LeakingBusinessObject
1         char[] <- String <- OkayBusinessObject
```

Comment: Some people like yourkit for this.

Comment: @bmargulies : what feature of yourkit allows for approximating the owner of low level objects? The closest thing I could find was : https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/mem_method_back_traces.jsp but requires the yourkit process to attach (https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/allocations.jsp) while running which I don't have the luxury of doing. I only have heap dumps.

Comment: I do not know. Thus a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The heap walker in [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) has a view that shows cumulated incoming references. Below you see chains of incoming references for all `int[]` arrays on the heap:

[image]

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler

Comment: Is it showing that of all the "array content", 12 or ~2MB can start from referent, 12 or ~2MB from bImg, etc... The sum is over 100% because referent, bImg, etc some are simultaneously pointing to raster?

Comment: "The sum is over 100% because referent, bImg, etc some are simultaneously pointing to raster?" That is correct.